# How to do update dropdown & how to make selected value for validation purpose in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In my view method, my selected dropdown like this. My problem are:-

1. How do I retrieve data from a database if I'm using the dropdown field? (Update Method)
2. How do I want to make the dropdown selected? (Validation & Show Method)

   ```
                         <div>
                            <x-label for="type" :value="__('Choose pizza type:')" />
                                <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
                                    <option selected disabled>Please choose</option>
                                    <option value="Chicken" {{ $value->type =="Chicken" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Chicken</option>
                                    <option value="Seafood" {{ $value->type =="Seafood" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Seafood</option>
                                    <option value="Beef" {{ $value->type =="Beef" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Beef</option>
                                    <option value="Prawn" {{ $value->type =="Prawn" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Prawn</option>
                                    <option value="Tuna" {{ $value->type =="Tuna" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Tuna</option>
                                </select>
                                <span style="color:red">@error('type'){{ $message }} @enderror</span>
                        </div>
   ```

I got an error as shown below:-

> Attempt to read property "type" on string (View:
> /home/vagrant/Projects/firstBlog/resources/views/pizzas/index.blade.php)

Comment: `$value['type']` try this first

Comment: @A.ANoman got this error -> TypeError
Cannot access offset of type string on string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a drop-down variable, you must send it as an array

- HTML Code:

```
<div>
                         <x-label for="type" :value="__('Choose pizza type:')" />
                             <select name="type[]" id="type" class="form-control">
                                 <option selected disabled>Please choose</option>
                                 <option value="Chicken" {{ $value->type =="Chicken" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Chicken</option>
                                 <option value="Seafood" {{ $value->type =="Seafood" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Seafood</option>
                                 <option value="Beef" {{ $value->type =="Beef" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Beef</option>
                                 <option value="Prawn" {{ $value->type =="Prawn" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Prawn</option>
                                 <option value="Tuna" {{ $value->type =="Tuna" ? 'selected' : '' }}>Tuna</option>
                             </select>
                             <span style="color:red">@error('type'){{ $message }} @enderror</span>
                     </div>
```

- validation(in controller):

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'type' => 'required|...'
        ]);
```

Comment: yes ! Thank you! buy why my created_at updated_at NULL...

Comment: u can for saving use down code:
$x = new Class($request->all());
$x->type()->attach($request->input('type'));

Comment: its not for type, its for adding the pizza menu. when admin add new pizza menu, supposed the timestamps not null, but my one, its NULL

Comment: below shown my migration coding.. the timestamps is there but not correct with my time

Comment: I think you are use insert method instade of create method.
Create method automatically add timestamp for created_at and updated_at field.
Example code: `$pizza::create($request->all());`

Comment: Another question: timestamp is null or it is wrong value???!!!

Comment: and for your another question, the timestamp is not null but it get the time is not my current time, it late 7 hours..

Comment: If you using Eloquent just you must change your project timezone in `config/app.php`
 and the timestamp is ok, 

Example: `'timezone' => 'UTC',` to `'timezone' => 'Asia/Dhaka',` You need to adjust your timezone based on your location.

Comment: im in malaysia, so i put 'timezone' => 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur', still not work, late 7 hours

Comment: Check your `.env`  file,maby timezone is set in `.env` and if is true you must change that whit `.env`.

Or maby after `'timezone'` in  `config\app.php` this value is seted again

Answer (score 0):

I get it correct this ways:-

```
                        <div>
                            <x-label for="type" :value="__('Choose pizza type:')" />
                                <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
                                    <option selected disabled>Please choose</option>
                                    <option value="Chicken"{{ $Info->type =="Chicken" ? 'selected':''}}>Chicken</option>
                                    <option value="Seafood"{{ $Info->type =="Seafood" ? 'selected':''}}>Seafood</option>
                                    <option value="Beef"{{ $Info->type =="Beef" ? 'selected':''}}>Beef</option>
                                    <option value="Prawn"{{ $Info->type =="Prawn" ? 'selected':''}}>Prawn</option>
                                    <option value="Tuna"{{ $Info->type =="Tuna" ? 'selected':''}}>Tuna</option>
                                </select>
                                <span style="color:red">@error('type'){{ $message }} @enderror</span>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my migration tables:-

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pizzas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->string('base');
    });
}
```